# UITableView Swift not scrolling Swift

Tags: uitableview, swift

UITableView Swift not scrolling. Guys I have this table view with three different cells and the table view renders on the simulator just fine but when i scroll it immediately jumps back to the top.

import UIKit

```
class WalkthroughScreen2ViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.scrollEnabled = true

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return 4
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->
        UITableViewCell {

            println(indexPath.row)
            if(indexPath.row == 0){

                var cell: wkscreen2Cell1TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell1") as wkscreen2Cell1TableViewCell

                return cell
            }
            if(indexPath.row == 1){

                var cell: wkscreen2Cell2TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell2") as wkscreen2Cell2TableViewCell

                return cell
            }
            if(indexPath.row == 2){
                println("cell3")
                var cell: wkscreen2Cell3TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell3") as wkscreen2Cell3TableViewCell

                return cell
            }
            return UITableViewCell()

    }




}
```

Comment: Swift has nothing to do with this question other than it's the programming language you wrote it in. Tagging this question "Swift" is fine but "UITableView Swift not scrolling Swift" and "UITableView Swift not scrolling." are of no help to anyone.

Comment: What happens when you change tableView.estimatedRowHeight to tableView.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Comment: when I change the rows have a height of 300 and anything beyond 300px is not displayed

Comment: Are your cells correctly using autolayout?

Comment: yeah they are using auto layout

Comment: Sure, but are they laid out correctly is my question :) Can you provide a test case project?

Comment: I just created a new empty project dragged a table view in to the view controller and ran the simulator .. I have the same problem it scrolls but doesn't stay it jumps back to the top immediately.

Comment: Right, so can you post this test case somewhere?

Comment: how to post the test case . I can zip a test project and send it to you

Comment: Yeah just zip it up and post it online, and post the link

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8226ksj82vnvvxf/Dashboard.zip?dl=0

Comment: this is the dropbox link just run it in the simulator and try to scroll you will understand the problem I'm facing.

Comment: This is normal tableview behavior. You have a single cell that is shorter than the height of the device. The tableview will always snap back like this if there's not enough cells to actually scroll. What you're seeing is a scroll view's (patented) rubber-banding effect.

Comment: yeah i facing that with when i have 3 cells and the cells have enough height to scroll to. How do I fix it then

Comment: Yeah, so I was really asking you to produce a test project that actually showed your problem. We're going to go around in circles and you don't have enough Stack Overflow reputation to chat.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8226ksj82vnvvxf/Dashboard.zip?dl=0

Comment: this is a new project where I have 3 cells with content . i still see that rubber band effect instead of the cells scrolling

Comment: So the problem is that you haven't applied any constraints to the tableview, so it's actually still taller than your device and doesn't need to "scroll". Notice also that there are big red exclamation points in your storyboard scenes? Yeah you need to fix those.

Comment: I'm a rookie iOS developer so the constraints to the table view has gone over my head , could you please point me to a link where I can read about it or just fix them in the sample project so the I can understand. thanks a lot for you time, advice and help

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8226ksj82vnvvxf/Dashboard.zip?dl=0

Comment: I got rid of all the errors in the view . I still face the problem

Comment: I was facing the same issue, and applying constraints like @mattyohe said did fix my issue. Thanks matt :)

Answer (score 6):

I landed on your question, because I had the same one.

To scroll in a simulator, you press and move your cursor up and down. If you are still not able to scroll, it must be a bug.

Comment: WOW @ujjiwal-nadhan thank you!  New to Swift and the simulator and did not know this. Very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Your TableView must be scroll, when count of your cells > 10, for example(4-inch screen). Test to do: Add ten cells for TableView. And it must be worked.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you `return 4` in `numberOfRowsInSection` when you are obviously only showing 3 cells ? Have you tried setting that to 3 ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After putting "tableView.dataSource = self" and "tableView.delegate = self" on "viewDidLoad()", the problem was solved.

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

```
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

quit the stimulator, clean shift+command+k then run the (command+R) should work.